# postgres sphinx search order

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

I have a postgres install with Sphinx and when I run query I want that most relevant records to be selected first. In other words, I want the following query first:

```
query="word1 & word2 & word3"
```

and then, if nothing selected,

```
query="word1 | word2 | word3"
```

How to configure sphinx for that needs? Sphinx config is default

Comment: Maybe it will work is you just  use plain "word1 word2 word3" and adjust ranking mode? So, docs which have all of words will be ranked high than documents with only some words.

Comment: I would be hjappy to do so, but I am using sphinx-postgres extention and sphinx_select function. I'm not sure how to do that there. Thanks

Comment: Well actully want `word1 | word2 | word3` with a particular ranking so that the ones that contain them all show first. THe resultset of "word1 | word2 | word3" will contain all that in "word1 word2 word3" documents - but the reverse does NOT hold true. Want the most permissive query, not the most restrictive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well https://github.com/andy128k/pg-sphinx says

```
sphinx_select(
/*index*/     varchar,
/*query*/     varchar,
/*condition*/ varchar,
/*order*/     varchar,
/*offset*/    int,
/*limit*/     int,
/*options*/   varchar)
```

And from http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select you want a OPTIONS clause to change the ranking (a `ranker` option)

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting

So would try

```
sphinx_select(...., "word1 | word2 | word3", ..., "ranker=wordcount")
```

(edited to show the query in place too, need **the OR query for this to work**! see comments above)

(wordcount ranker, is very basic, but should do the exact criteria you want)

But can play with custom expressions, not great, but get you started...

```
sphinx_select(....,  "ranker=expr('sum(word_count+hit_count+lccs+exact_order)+bm25')")
```

MUCH more detail... http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/

Comment: Thanks, but I search for 5 words and one of them doesn't exist at all in the db, I search 'downloader' but only 'downloading' in the db. and ranker=wordcount does not find anythind, as well as any other ranker. The only way I make it work is just find with & and then with |. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't make sense. IF enter "word1 | word2 | word3" as query. Even if there are no documents with word2, documents with word1 and/or word2 wills till be returned. changing the ranker only changes the ordering (well the weight, which changes the default order) - maybe thats the problem, you are explicitly ordering results, so not ordering by sphixn weight